# Tridion 2009 Custom Page: How to fix the error message "Object required: 'TMSMail'"?

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

We are using a custom page on Tridion 2009.
This custom page was working fine earlier.

Recently we have moved this to another server. Now this custom page is throwing error saying that

```
Error 424 occurred while rendering the Page: Object required: 'TMSMail' 
(source: WriteOut TMSMail.GetHTMLStartTag())
```

Please suggest on how to fix this.

Comment: What is your custom page trying to do?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov: We are using this page for sending emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When am looking around DLL's and the tridion MMC Snap-In, I got an Idea.

What will happen if we add the below entry on MMC Snap-In

1. Click on Script Extension
2. Add a new object

   - **TCM Object Name:** `TMSMail`
   - **COM Object Name:** `TMSScriptExtension.ProfileHelper`

### EDIT:

Finally, I have solved after a lot of trails.

Below are the steps I followed to solve:-

1. First I have added above entry on MMC Snap-In
2. I found the dll location for this extension and registered this using **`regsvr32`** command
3. Restarted **`COM+`** service

Now tried it, its working fine.

Thanks a lot for the inputs.

Comment: It indeed looks like that new machine doesn't have the necessary Outbound E-mail components installed. Did adding the script extension help? You'll probably also need the mailer itself, so I suggest running the installer.

Comment: Siva is correct. You need to register the OE Script Extension. 

Since the Script Extension is deprecated, I would also recommend actually changing to use the Template Building Blocks instead, but I know that is not always feasible :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and PeterKjaer: Initially when I tried adding the entry, its not solved. After a lot of research on the server, I found the dll location and tried registering. Finally when i restarted the COM+ then its started working.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be specific to the code of your custom page rather than a generic Tridion error.

If you're using a third party library (from tmssoftware.com perhaps?) check that it's installed/available on your new server.

Also, the DLL with the TmsMail class may need to be added to the GAC or the registry (look up regasm.exe on how to do this).

Comment: I think TMSMail would be part of Tridion installation, I guess and I'm didn't find the location where this DLL is located for registering it.

Comment: Nickoli, initially I didnt find the location of dll. After a lot of workaround I found the location and tried registering. But I didnt see any sort of change. At last, I tried by restarting the COM+ then its started working.